# How do I grab contents of a div using XPATH based on text in the previous div?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to grab the link text from the following code using XPATH based on the text: "Key features"

I am trying various versions of this:

```
//div[starts-with(., 'Key features')]/following-sibling::td/li
```

But don't seem to be having much luck.

```
<div class="product-detail">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="sixteen wide tablet six wide computer column top aligned">
            <div class="block__title"><img src="https://test.png" alt="Key features">
                <div class="title">Key features</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sixteen wide tablet ten wide computer column top aligned">
            <div class="block__content">
                <table class="ui unstackable fixed table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="one-column">
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>10X Rewards (10 points or 4 Miles) for every S$1 spent on Shoes + Bags + Clothes at Online, Retail or Department stores, locally and overseas</li>
                                    <li>Enjoy discounts of up to 50% at Foodpanda, Lazada, Zalora, Reebonz, and more</li>
                                    <li>S$1 spent = 1 Rewards point (All other spend)</li>
                                    <li>First year fee waived for Principal and two (2) Supplementary cards</li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want to get link text from HTML that contains no links?!

Comment: Sorry, meant "list" :)

Comment: Try `//div[.//div="Key features"]/following-sibling::div//li`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved this for anyone else reading this:

```
//div[starts-with(., 'Key features')]/following-sibling::div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li
```